# How to create a header/footer in new docx document?

Tags: java, header, docx, xwpf

I would like to create a header and footer on a docx document (a new one and not existing one) with XWPF jars (apache poi).

When I use `XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy policy = document.getHeaderFooterPolicy();` policy is null, so I would know how to create it in a new document.

```
CustomXWPFDocument document = new CustomXWPFDocument();
XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy policy = document.getHeaderFooterPolicy();
XWPFHeader head = policy.createHeader(policy.DEFAULT);
head.getListParagraph().get(0).createRun().setText("Hello Header World!");
CTP ctP1 = CTP.Factory.newInstance();
CTR ctR1 = ctP1.addNewR();
CTText t = ctR1.addNewT();
t.setStringValue("Paragraph in header");
XWPFParagraph p1 = new XWPFParagraph(ctP1, document);
XWPFParagraph[] pars = new XWPFParagraph[1];
pars[0] = p1;
policy.createHeader(policy.FIRST, pars);
```

Answer (score 1):

You must add a section property to the `XWPFDocument doc` if not already present by using following code

```
CTBody body = doc.getDocument().getBody();
CTSectPr sectPr = body.isSetSectPr()? body.getSectPr() : body.addNewSectPr();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void setFooter(XWPFDocument document, String footerText) {
    CTP ctpFooter = CTP.Factory.newInstance();
    ctpFooter.addNewR().addNewT();

    XWPFParagraph footerParagraph = new XWPFParagraph(ctpFooter, document);
    XWPFRun footerRun = createFormattedRun(footerParagraph);
    footerRun.setFontSize(6);
    footerRun.setText(footerText);
    XWPFParagraph[] parsFooter = new XWPFParagraph[1];
    parsFooter[0] = footerParagraph;

    CTSectPr sectPr = document.getDocument().getBody().addNewSectPr();
    XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy policy = new XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy(document, sectPr);
    policy.createFooter(XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy.DEFAULT, parsFooter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but didn't find any solution. In this case I created template docx file with header and footer and than change them. This practice I found in [Apache mail archives](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/poi-user/201301.mbox/%3CCAPPbLhpiHfhvs5AXDZv4B2UYZyMvzG8+Uz+Rfa9NuM-g3Os9=g@mail.gmail.com%3E).

Comment: thank you, i saw it befor but doesn't helping for my application. my document is generated and don't have tamplate, but i can use one template only for the recuperation of the header and footer and inser it in the generated document... and don't know how to do