# Java: XWPFWordExtractor.getText() throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, ms-word, apache-poi, docx

I am using Apache POI to create a `.docx` file with the following code:

```
XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
run.setText(text);
String filePath = outputPathWithoutExtension + ".docx";
try {
    FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(new File(filePath));
    document.write(stream);
    stream.close();
} catch (IOException exception) {
    LOGGER.error("Could not create file '{}'", filePath);
}
```

and then I try to read it with the following code:

```
FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
try {
    XWPFDocument docx = new XWPFDocument(fileStream);
    XWPFWordExtractor wordExtractor = new XWPFWordExtractor(docx);
    text = wordExtractor.getText();
} catch (IOException | POIXMLException | OfficeXmlFileException
            | NullPointerException exception) {
     LOGGER.error("Could not load file - Exception: {}", exception.getMessage());
}
```

On the line where I call `getText()`, it is throwing a `NullPointerException`:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.poi.xwpf.extractor.XWPFWordExtractor.extractHeaders(XWPFWordExtractor.java:162)
at org.apache.poi.xwpf.extractor.XWPFWordExtractor.getText(XWPFWordExtractor.java:87)
```

The issue appears to be that `extractText` calls `extractHeaders` with the `XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy` of the document ... which in my case is null.  When it tries to use it on its very first line ... boom.

I tried to create my own "header/footer policy" like so:

```
try {
    new XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy(document);
} catch (IOException | XmlException exception) {
    LOGGER.warn("Could not create output document header - "
           + "document might not be readable in all readers");
}
```

However, that itself throws a `NullPointerException` because it tries to access the "SectPr" of the document via `doc.getDocument().getBody().getSectPr()`, which returns null ... and then the first time it uses that ... boom.

So, my question is: I'm clearly not creating the `XWPFDocument` correctly ... could someone set me straight?

Side note: If I open the file in Word, the file looks fine.  If between the creation and reading of the file, I open it, edit it, save it, and close it, then the call to `getText()` executes as expected with no `NullPointerException`.  Word must fill in the appropriate header/footer policy on save.

Comment: Looks to be a bug - did you try reporting it as a bug to [the Apache POI bug tracker](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=POI)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha!  I found my answer here: [How to create a header/footer in new docx document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27128317/how-to-create-a-header-footer-in-new-docx-document)

I basically just gave up one step too soon.  Adding this code to the creation of the document allowed it to be read:

```
// Add a SectPr and header/footer policy so document can be opened and read by POI
try {
    document.getDocument().getBody().addNewSectPr();
    new XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy(document);
} catch (IOException | XmlException exception) {
    LOGGER.warn("Could not create output document header - "
            + "document might not be readable in all readers");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    //---------------------Modify Footer or Headder change footer x headder 
//If you need some help tell me. agustinoscarmendez@gmail.com
try {
            XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open("C:\\Users\\amendez\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\PuertasSRL_Presupuesto\\Resources\\Words y Excel Examples\\Modelos de EPC.docx"));
            //XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();
            CTSectPr sectPr = doc.getDocument().getBody().addNewSectPr();
            XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy policy = new XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy(doc, sectPr);
            XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy hfp = doc.getHeaderFooterPolicy();
            //XWPFFooter ffffff = hfp.getFooter(1); //Para cambiar el footer de la primera pagina
            XWPFFooter ffffff = hfp.getDefaultFooter();//to change all pages
            for (XWPFParagraph p : ffffff.getParagraphs()) {
            List<XWPFRun> runs = p.getRuns();
            if (runs != null) {
                for (XWPFRun r : runs) {
                    String text = r.getText(0);
                    if (text != null && text.contains("VPALABRA")) { //if the text contains the word you want to change
                        text = text.replace("VPALABRA", "twitter: GugaMendez"); //change the  word to the new word
                        r.setText(text, 0);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\amendez\\Desktop\\Agustín\\carpetas\\write-test4.docx");
                    doc.write(out);
                    out.close();
                    System.out.println("Done perro");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
```